# Java parse xml i18n

Tags: java, xml, internationalization

I'm doing i18n for my web app and I have a list of error messages in an xml file, like this:

```
<ErrorList>
  <Errors culture="en">

    <Error id="InvalidBooking">
        <Heading1>We are unable to find your booking.</Heading1>
        <Heading2></Heading2>
        <Description1>Please try again.</Description1>
        <Description2>OR</Description2>
        <Description3>Seek assistance at the Check-In counter.</Description3>
        <Description4></Description4>
    </Error> 
 </Errors>

  <Errors culture="zh">

        <Error id="InvalidBooking">
        <Heading1>我们无法找到您的预订。</Heading1>
        <Heading2></Heading2>
        <Description1>请再试一次。.</Description1>
        <Description2>或</Description2>
        <Description3>请联系登机柜台寻求帮助。</Description3>
        <Description4></Description4>
        </Error>

  </Errors>

</ErrorList>
```

I use the DOM xml parser to load the error messages. Then I get the specific error by matching Error id:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().
                newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(xml);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Error");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                Error _error = new Error();

                _error.setKey(eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                _error.setHeading1(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Heading1").item(0).getTextContent());
                _error.setHeading2(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Heading2").item(0).getTextContent());
                _error.setDescription1(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Description1").item(0).getTextContent());
                _error.setDescription2(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Description2").item(0).getTextContent());
                _error.setDescription3(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Description3").item(0).getTextContent());
      _error.setDescription5(eElement.getElementsByTagName("Description4").item(0).getTextContent());

                getErrors().add(_error);
```

How do I go about specifying the culture id to only load the error messages in that section? For example, when I switch to chinese, it looks up the Errors culture="zh" and only parses in that section?
Thanks.

Comment: The main question here is, why you have implemented it like that? What's wrong about plain, old Java properties files? How about translators? How they are suppose to translate this? It seems unmaintainable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop you should be able to get the attribute for the nNode and check it.

```
if ("zh".equals(nNode.getAttribute("culture"))) {
          // do it here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work. Once the locale matched the 'culture', I used another for loop to parse the errors.